# How to profile a headless Java application, running remotely?

Tags: java, profiling, headless

I have a headless Java application, running on a remote server as a daemon-style process.

I want to extract Java level profiling information from the process, of the sort displayed by [JVisualVM](http://visualvm.java.net/). For example, it should show method invocation times and so on.

What is the best way of doing this? My understanding is that JVisualVM does not profile when connecting remotely.

Ideally, the profiling information would be stored in a file for later inspection, in a manner similar to Java heap generation (with jmap) and later analysis (with a heap inspector).

Comment: You can do this with commercial profilers, but I don't know how to do it with VisualVM.

Comment: If that's the most general, current truth, it might be worth promoting that to an answer.

Comment: If no one else knows a way, I will. Perhaps Java's security model which allows you to inject code on the same machine, but not from another??

Comment: Is it a unix server? You can always run JVisualVM remotely via X

Comment: Yeah it is... good point, I did think of that but forgot about it. I'd still like to know any approaches that don't require a connection though and log to file. Might be worth promoting that to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NetBeans profiler](http://netbeans.org/features/java/profiler.html) remote profiling capability.

> ## **Remote Profiling**
>
> Profile an application that is running on a different system than your NetBeans IDE. The profiler's remote pack can be installed on a remote system, allowing you to profile an application that is started on that system.

In fact, [VisualVM is based on it](https://blogs.oracle.com/nbprofiler/entry/profiling_with_visualvm_part_1).

> Beside various monitoring features, the tool contains a **built-in profiler based on the NetBeans profiler**. While the profiler UI in VisualVM looks simple (especially when compared to the NetBeans profiler), the profiling capabilities are almost as powerful as in NetBeans.

Here is a detailed blog post about [Profiling a Java remote server using Netbeans](http://blog.thecodingmachine.com/node/80).

Comment: This does answer the question. I think initially I was looking for something that would do recording and not actually wanting to connect to the process, but was not explicit about this. But this answers the question as asked so have some points ;)

Answer (score 1):

According to the link you will have to set up jstatd and jmx:
http://javadevsoup.blogspot.de/2012/02/remote-java-profiling-using-visual-vm.html

Answer (score 0):

I just found another product that I think does this: http://chrononsystems.com/products/chronon-recording-server